# Выборка из составного типа с применением агрегатной функции (Версия postgre 9.2.18)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Есть Составной тип:

```
Create type ComprositionPrixod AS (
    Name character varying,
    Count numeric,
    Uint character varying,
    Price numeric
);
```

Он используется в таблице:

```
 CREATE TABLE "Prixod" (
        "ID" serial NOT NULL,
        "NameSklad" varchar not null,
        "Composition" ComprositionPrixod[] NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT Prixod_pk PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
    );
```

Надо выбрать и посчитать данные из таблицы одним запросом. Работало так:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(round(sum(p.Count),2),0) psum, COALESCE(round((sum(p.Price)/sum(p.Count)), 2),0) pavg FROM "Prixod", unnest("Prixod"."Composition") p  where "Prixod"."NameSklad" = $1  and p.Name = $2;
```

Но на сервере установлена старая версия postgre, и вот сразу с unnest не работает пишет:

```
ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
LINE 2: SELECT * FROM "Prixod", unnest("Prixod"."Composition") k WHE...
                                       ^
********** Ошибка **********

ERROR: function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
SQL-состояние: 42P10
Символ: 33
```

Вынужден переписывать запрос, вот одна из попыток:

```
select w."Composition"
from (SELECT "Prixod"."Composition" as "Composition" 
FROM "Prixod" where "Prixod"."NameSklad" = 'Sklad') w 
where (w."Composition")[0].Name = 'Огурчик';
```

Но так сморит только на каждый столбец по отдельности. Пробовал так: 
[:3] и по разному, выдается ошибка на скобку.

Как мне это реализовать правильно? Выборку надо сделать именно по имени склада и товару.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в версии СУБД, на PostgreSQL 9.6 тоже не удастся выполнить неявное объединение таблицы с результатом развёртки собственных полей. Проблемы две. Первая в том, что у вас чудовищная структура базы данных, далёкая от какой-либо степени нормализации. Вторая - это непонимание вами принципов функционирования реляционных БД и недостаточное знание SQL. Реализовать запрос в том виде, в котором вы хотите, можно:

```
select
  namesklad,
  csum,
  round(psum/csum, 2) as pavg
from (
    select
      a.NameSklad,
      coalesce(round(sum((b.composition).Count), 2), 0) as csum,
      coalesce(round(sum((b.composition).Price), 2), 0) as psum
    from Prixod as a
    inner join (
        select id, unnest(composition) as composition
        from Prixod
    ) as b
      using (id)
    group by a.NameSklad
) as x;
```

но я крайне рекомендую вам либо изменить изменить структуру БД, либо перейти на NoSQL.

Comment: Я так понимаю резонанс вызывает использование сложных типов? (Это я про структуру БД). По поводу недостатков знаний в SQL, тут и сказать против нечего =)

Comment: на 9.6 запрос, который я продемонстрировал работал =(

Comment: Использование массивов уже нарушает требования первой нормальной формы. Нужны очень веские причины для того, чтобы их использовать. И уж точно их не стоит использовать тогда, когда по ним требуется выполнять сложные запросы. Использование же массива составных типов там, где можно было просто добавить полей - совсем непонятное решение.

Comment: Я представляю, что все это можно делать в отдельной таблице. Но вы сказали про просто добавить полей, можно не много поподробнее этот момент, спасибо? (Там массив сложного типа)

Comment: Не вижу проблем с тем, чтобы добавить в таблицу Prixod поля из ComprositionPrixod, а вместо использования массива просто добавлять нужное количество строк.

Comment: Дублирование всего остального то есть. Спасибо за консультацию. =)

Comment: А не могли бы еще подсказать как произвести update записи?

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если не затруднит: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655514/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B2-postgresql