# Обновить составной тип в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Есть Составной тип:

```
Create type ComprositionPrixod AS (
    Hash character varying,
    Name character varying,
    Count numeric,
    Uint character varying,
    Price numeric
);
```

Он используется в таблице:

```
 CREATE TABLE "Prixod" (
        "ID" serial NOT NULL,
        "NameSklad" varchar not null,
        "Composition" ComprositionPrixod[] NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT Prixod_pk PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
    );
```

Как сделать запрос на обновление? К примеру Count по Hash в составном типе?

Comment: По Hash? Объясните как можно подробнее, что хотите обновить и чем.

Comment: Hash не скопировал, сейчас думаю все понятно =) А так: Есть определенный Hash продукта, мне надо во всех записях найти соответствие по данному hash и обновить (к примеру) количество Count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже писал в вашем прошлом вопросе, но повторю, что лучше либо привести структуру данных к нормальной форме, либо использовать NoSQL.

Чтобы обновить поле элемента массива составного типа, вам нужно знать индекс элемента в массиве:

```
UPDATE Prixod SET
  Composition[1].Count = 10
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT
          id,
          unnest(Composition) AS items
        FROM Prixod
    ) AS explode
    WHERE (explode.items).Hash = 'd8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4'
);
```

Узнать индекс элемента в массиве можно на версиях PostgreSQL от 9.5 с помощью функции array_position(), но для этого надо знать точные значения всех полей элемента.

На версиях PostgreSQL от 9.3 можно произвести обновление не зная индекса, но это будет обновление всего массива и опять же надо знать точные значения всех полей требуемого элемента:

```
UPDATE Prixod SET
  Composition = array_replace(Composition, ('d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4', 'qwerty', 5, 'kg', 100), ('d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4', 'qwerty', 10, 'kg', 100))
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT
          id,
          unnest(Composition) AS items
        FROM Prixod
    ) AS explode
    WHERE (explode.items).Hash = 'd8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4'
);
```